# Ember Testing: Why use Assert.?

Tags: ember.js, qunit, ember-qunit, ember-testing

I see a lot of examples (including ember-cli generated tests) that use `assert.function()` but I can use the function as is, so am I doing something wrong, or do examples just show not-really-necessary qualifiers?

For example, either of these work in a new generated unit test:

`assert.expect(1);`

`expect(1);`

Why ever do the first one if the second one works?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a [QUnit change](http://qunitjs.com/upgrade-guide-2.x/#replace-global-assertions-with-assert-arguments), not an Ember one. QUnit is changing their API as they move towards 2.0. You can use the global versions now, but they'll be removed in 2.0 so it's probably a good idea to use the `assert.*` versions now so you don't have to change the code later.

Comment: agreed -if you look at the test syntax with ember-cli you will see assert (the variable). If you didn't see it you would be relying on some global like @GJK mentioned